# Stochastic Control

Tags: optimization, stochastic-analysis, optimal-control

I would like to solve the following stochastic dynamic programming in the discrete-case and continuous case:

Let the state variables have the following dynamics:
\begin{align*}
dS_t = \mu S_t dt + \sigma S_tdW_t \\
dX_t = -\alpha_t dt
\end{align*}
where $S_0 = s_0$ and $X_0 = N$ and $X_T = 0$. (an inventory-like problem)

We define a continuous cost function $f$ and 
I am interested in minimizing the value function :

\begin{align}
U^{(\alpha)}(t,S,X) = \mathbb{E}_{t,s,x}\left[\int_{t}^{T}f(u,S_u,\alpha_u)du+ g(T,S_T,X_T=0)\text{ | } S_t = s, X_t = x  \right] 
\end{align}
My cost function $f$ can writen as $f(u,S_u,\alpha_u) = g(u,S_u,\alpha_u)\alpha_u$ which comes from the fact that initially I was minimizing:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[-\int_{0}^{T}{g(t,S_t,\alpha_t)dX_t}  \right]
\end{align}

Using the theory of dynamic programming I can end up with the following HJB:

\begin{equation}
\partial_t U + \mathcal{L}U + \inf_{\alpha}{h(\alpha)} =0
\end{equation}

where

\begin{equation*}
h(\alpha) = -\alpha\partial_XU + f(t,S,\alpha)
\end{equation*}
and $\mathcal{L}$ is the linear operator w.r.t $S$. Usually to solve this we minimize $h$ and reinject the optimal $\alpha$ into the HJB to end up with a PDE. But what happens if the solution is for example 0? I happen to have $f(t,S,\alpha) = g(t,S)\alpha$ or $f(t,S,\alpha) = g(t,S)\alpha^3$. What is the theory to follow in order to solve this HJB?

Now I am interested in a discrete-time framework where updating the state variable $X_t$ happens only at discrete $t_i$ ($\partial_XU = 0$).

The value function $U(t,S,X)$ satisfies a differential equation which has no dependence on $X$:
\begin{align}
\partial_t{U} + \mathcal{L}U &= 0 &  t \in(t_{i-1},t_i), \text{ } i = 1,2...,N
\end{align}
The updating of $X_t$ only occurs at the trading dates. Upon buying a quantity $\alpha_ih$ at $t_i$, the targeted quantity drops to $X-\alpha_ih$ and the liquidation cost jumps  with a jump condition given by the discrete-time framework of the dynamic programming principle:
\begin{equation}
U(t_i^-,S,X) = \inf_{\alpha_{i} | \alpha_ih \leq N-X}\left\{U(t_i^+,S,X+\alpha_ih) + \hat{f}(t_i^+,S,\alpha_ih) \right\}
\end{equation}
I can solve this numerically but end up having results I don't understand. For example that my control remains the same along the state variable $S$. Does it look like normal? Is it always the case for certain form of the cost function and/or the dependance of the state variable of the control?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For the discrete-time case I would recommend the book: D.P. Bertsekas and S.E. Shreve, Stochastic optimal control: the discrete time case, Academic press, 1978. However, in that case you also need a discrete-time dynamical model for your system.